# How to change the widgets property if I use QT Designer

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, properties

I am using Visual Studio 2022 and C++ QT 5.14.2.

I used QT Designer to setup a PushButton and a LineEdit, and I gave them some initial property. But I met problem in button clicked signal slot function, this is my code:

```
void SocketChat::on_connectButton_clicked() {
    appendMessage(ui.connectButton->text());  // output button's text
    if (ui.addrEdit->isEnabled() && ui.portEdit->isEnabled()) {
        // disabled
        ui.addrEdit->setEnabled(false);
        ui.connectButton->setText(QStringLiteral("Disconnect"));
        appendMessage(ui.connectButton->text());  // output button's text
    }
    if (ui.addrEdit->isEnabled() && !ui.portEdit->isEnabled()) {
        ui_notification->setText(QStringLiteral("Please stop listening."));
    }
    if (!ui.addrEdit->isEnabled() && ui.portEdit->isEnabled()) {
        // enabled
        ui.addrEdit->setEnabled(true);
        ui.connectButton->setText(QStringLiteral("Connect"));
    }
}
```

Button's text was assigned to 'Connect' in QT Designer, and after the function finished, the button's text is still 'Connect'.

`appendMessage` function output two words for every time I clicked:

> Connect
> Disconnect

The click function works properly but and the button's text was changed successfully in this function. But after the function finished, everything recovered. The button's text is still 'Connect'. I tried `repaint()` and `update()`, they're unable to work.

**How can I change the widgets' property?** It seems that these properties cannot be initialized once they have been changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You are missing some `else` keywords.**

Note that when your button is clicked the first `if`-block (labeled "// disabled") is execute and it disables the `ui.addrEdit` button. Due to the missing `else` keyword the program then also checks the conditions of the other `if` statements. And since the button is now disabled the last condition evaluates to true and therefore the block labeled "// enabled" is also run. This is not what you want.

Comment: Thanks! Maybe I need take some breaks, this is a stupid mistake. In my code style, I should add `return;` in every `if` statement.

Comment: Adding `return`s certainly will do the trick, too. I personally like the `else` keyword because it communicates "only one of these will execute". But I don't want to start the whole "when to use early-return" discussion. **Being consistent with your code style is the thing that matters most.** So +1 for that.